# Trying to understand the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test in MATLAB

Tags: distributions, matlab, goodness-of-fit, kolmogorov-smirnov-test

I have two sets of data, $\mathbf{d_1}$ and $\mathbf{d_2}$ which I want to test to see if they are drawn from the same distribution using the two-sample KS test in MATLAB.

My understanding of the KS test is that you first compute the cumulative distribution function for both datasets and then find the maximum difference between the two distributions and this will be your D-statistic.

However, when I try to do it myself I get a "slightly" different D-statistic than MATLAB outputs. Also my computed CDF is "slightly" different from the CDF computed inside the MATLAB function `kstest2` but very similar.

From built-in MATLAB KS-test:

[image]

From my own calculation:

[image]

From the built in KS-test in MATLAB the D-statistic is 0.09 for this particular random set. Whereas my calculated D-statistic is 0.064. I've run it a variety of times and the difference between the two D-statistics is usually quite small (e.g. 0.12 vs 0.1275 or 0.22 vs. 0.194). However, I find it strange that they are not the same. I'm assuming the error has to do with the way I am calculating the CDF. It also seems like the built-in kstest2 in MATLAB is doing some sort of binning of the data which, to me, seems a little sketchy. Also as the length of my vectors gets larger, the difference between the two methods is smaller. For example if I take vectors with length of 10,000 then D-statistic from kstest2 is e.g. 0.0127 while my own calculation gets D-statistic of e.g. 0.0129. So it seems that the two methods agree at the limit as N goes to infinity...

Here is a code sample:

```
%Two random vectors
N = 1000;
d1 = rand(N,1);
d2 = rand(N,1);

%Built in KS test. D is the D-statistic
[h,p,D] = kstest2(d1,d2);

%Compute my own CDF
cdf1 = sort(d1);
cdf2 = sort(d2);

%Compute my own D-statistic
D_alt = max(abs(cdf1-cdf2));

%In general "D_alt" is close to "D" but never the same...
```

Comment: (1) Why do your two graphics differ?  (2) You aren't computing the KS D statistic: you're computing the maximum difference between sorted values.  If it isn't plainly obvious that these are completely different, try it again but generate data uniformly distributed between, say, $0$ and $100$ rather than $0$ and $1.$

Comment: Ohhh thank you for this clarification. It just "clicked" as to what I was doing wrong. I was plotting the x coordinates as the y coordinate in the cdf....makes sense now. Thanks!